# Using tobit for a positively skewed variable

Tags: skewness, tobit-regression

I have a continuous dependent variable which is positively skewed. The relevant data is panel data.

Can we run a Tobit regression on this dependent variable?

Comment: But why would you want this?

Comment: Tobit implies either one limit or two limits on the response or outcome variable. What are they in your case?

Comment: I was firstly advised to do this. The argument was that Tobit could be used as an approximation to a positively skewed distribution. The dependent variable however does not have much zeros nor has the issue of censoring. I also tried using log(x + 0.5) since there a few zeros and used normal panel data such as fixed and random effects but under Tobit, you have more variables that are statistically significant than otherwise. I do apologise if my answer is not that informative or helpful. Thank you

Comment: That advice is puzzling to me. I can't imagine an implementation of Tobit without specifying a bound or bounds, and what would the upper bound be? I'd happily use generalized linear models with log link for data with some zeros. They have been extended to panel set-ups. Adding 0.5 and then taking logarithms is by comparison an arbitrary and unnecessary fudge.